# Command line glob to view multiple images using ImageMagick's display

Tags: terminal, wildcards, imagemagick

How can I open multiple images files using ImageMagick's `display` command? If I enter say `display *.png` in a directory containing multiple PNG files, only one is displayed. I think I'd prefer them to appear one at a time, but all at once could be useful too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't specify a [delay](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#delay), `imagemagick` will load the first image and wait for your input, that is

<kbd>SPACE</kbd> - load next image
<kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> - load previous image

If you want to display the images in sequence without interaction, use a delay:

```
display -delay 50 *.png
```

To display all of them you could try with

```
display 'vid:*.png'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to see all your images at once, you can use `montage` to group them into a single, temporary image in **ImageMagick**'s MIFF format (which is lossless regardless of whether image has alpha channels or 8/16/32 bit integer/float samples) and tell `display` to show that:

```
display <(montage *.png MIFF:-)
```

The nice thing about this is that `montage` will lay out your images sensibly according to how many you have:

If you have 3 images:

[image]

If you have 4 images:

[image]

If you have 8 images:

[image]

If you have 9 images:

[image]

---

If you prefer to layout your images yourself, rather than let `montage` do them automagically, you can specify how many columns (i.e. how many images across the screen) you'd like and it will make as many rows as necessary. So, say you wanted 3 images in each row:

```
display <(montage *.png -tile 3x MIFF:-)
```